# Understanding a question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If c is randomly chosen from the integers 20 to 99, inclusive, what is
>   the probability that $c^3-c$ is divisible by 12?

I have not got the question that what is implying by c?

> How to get the outcomes divisible by 12 ?

Comment: There are $80$ numbers available. Take $c=20$, then $c^3-c=7980$ is divisible by $12$; for some other number it couldn't be. For how many of the $80$ numbers is the result of $c^3-c$ divisible by $12$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think to a table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
c & c^3-c \\
\hline
20 & 7980 & \bullet \\
21 & 9240 & \bullet \\
22 & 10626 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
98 & 941094 \\
99 & 970200 & \bullet
\end{array}
$$
How many of the numbers in the right column are divisible by $12$ (marked with $\bullet$)? Let's say they are $d$; assuming that “random” means ”uniformly random”, you have $d$ favorable outcomes out of $80$, so the probability is $d/80$.

Now you have two paths: doing all the computations or finding a cleverer way that involves writing $c^3-c=(c-1)c(c+1)$ and reasoning about it.

Comment: I have got your reasoning. :) But how will we know that the numbers of the outcomes will be divisible by 12.?

Comment: @ComplexGuy Why should it? The question is to determine $d$,  not to prove it's divisible by $12$.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @ComplexGuy Can you see that $(c-1)c(c+1)$ is divisible by $3$ for any integer $c$? Now, if $c$ is odd, then $c-1$ *and* $c+1$ are even, so $(c-1)c(c+1)$ is also divisible by $4$. If $c$ is even, then $(c-1)c(c+1)$ is not divisible by $4$ unless…

Comment: Yes got it  $ODD=(99-21)/2+1=40$
Divisible by $4= (96-20)/4+1=20$
Total=$99-20+1=80$

P=Favorable/Total=$(40+20)/80=60/80=3/4$

Comment: @ComplexGuy Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: (Edited to include egreg's comments)

No matter whatever $c$ you take $c^3-c = (c-1).c.(c+1)$ is divisible by $3! = 6$.

So for $c^3-c$ to be divisible by 12, you will need $(c-1).c.(c+1)$ as even.odd.even and not odd.even.odd except when this even in the later expression  is a multiple of 4.

So probability = ?

Comment: Ehm, for $c=20$ you have “odd times even times odd”, but $20^3-20=7980=12\cdot 665$ *is* divisible by $12$.

Comment: Doesn't work for $4|c$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: factorise $c^3-c$. Observe that the factors are consecutive integers with the middle one being $c$.

Now think about what constraints must apply to $c$ for divisibility by $12=3 × 4$. For example if $c$ is odd then the product of the other two integers is divisible by $4$ so $c$ needs to be an odd multiple of $3$ unless one of the others is an even multiple of $3$ and so forth.